# tracker.js is hitting directly dispatcher URL? How to resolve that?

Tags: aem

I have a multiple publish instances and multiple dispatchers in Production environment of my website. While i see net tab in firefox, i see a failed request of tracker.js directly hitting to dispatcher URL.

GET http://web.dispatcher.com/libs/wcm/stats/tracker.js?blah-blah

where web.dispatcher.com

I feel dispatcher URL should not get exposed like this. And why even it is hitting dispatcher URL. Any ideas?
I feel either turn off the impressions tracker but not sure how to do that? Or rewrite the request to hide dispatcher. Any suggestions? And How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

if you go to [host]:[port]/system/console/configMgr you will see a configuration for "Day CQ WCM Page Statistics"

Modify that to configure the full url where you want the tracker to send it's requests to.

Additionally, this XHR request is generated by stats.jsp, which is generally included in your head.jsp.  If you simply remove that script include from your template (or change it to conditionally include, ie. to not include when WCMMode==DISABLED) you can stop that request from being generated.